# how do I retrieve an input variable onto a javascript controller in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a search input field and i am trying to send that input to a JavaScript variable that i'd like to use. this is in Angular

input

```
<input ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Search">
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('searchkingApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
//which code can i put under here?

//and end up having 

var searchedItem = //the string I have searched for..
```

I have the JavaScript file located in a different place from the HTML file.

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Any specific reason, why you want to access the variable in javascript outside of angular app? or is it with in the angular App but from a different controller or something

Comment: I want to perform a search on the github repository of which i can do with a hard coded variable. But now i'm trying to do a search and struggling to get the variable to the JavaScript file in order to use it. it's suppose to be a simple search but i'm missing something.

Comment: you just use $scope.searchText  in your controller to access the value.

Comment: it's like using an input in an HTML form then pushing that "string" or inserted item into another page to use it there. I can do it in PHP. But angular has that $scope thing in the .controller and i get lost there.

Comment: I understand now. I was confused when you meant javascript variable in a different file. Its a simple thing. You could use the answer I have for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.searchText = "Hello";
    $scope.search = function() {
      console.log($scope.searchText);
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <input ng-model="searchText" />
    <button ng-click="search()">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your logic to search on Github within the AngularJS App.

Inside `searchOnGithub()` method you can use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to call your PHP script passing the value of the variable `$scope.searchText` and then show the result in the view.

Hope this helps to start:

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.searchOnGithub = function() {
      // Do your logic to perform the search on Github
      console.clear();
      console.log($scope.searchText);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="searchOnGithub()" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Either if you manually add a `searchText` property to `$scope` or you just rely on `ng-model="searchText"` (this also automatically adds a property to `$scope`), your controller will access bound `<input>` value using `$scope.searchText`:

```
angular.module('searchkingApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
       var searchedItem = $scope.searchText;
  });
```

Now you can either do an action when users performs some event (for example, a *click event*) or watch `$scope.searchText` for changes:

```
<input type="text" ng-click="search()">

$scope.search = function() {
    // $scope.searchText will give the search terms
};
```

...or:

```
// You would go this way if you want to implement something like 
// Google Instant Search so you don't need to click anything, you perform
// searches whenever the <input> changes
$scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.searchText; }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // newValue contains current $scope.searchText value
});
```